# Custom Attribute Addition

Tags: custom-attributes, troubleshooting

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Hello Magento Geeks... need some helping hand.

**Story**

Adding custom attribute to custom module developed by 3rd party (with no documentation).
Field is part of social media links collection, and most of them been implemented before (twitter, facebook, youtube... now trying to add instagram).

Since I have no clue about Magento structure I ran -grep command to obtain all locations where other fields been mentioned in the code and modified code by adding new field. (tested, nothing got broken).

Added new attribute in the attribute set for the module. Checked DB if everything was added - everything in place.

Grep for usage of the tables from DB with those attributes, and added file with insert/update etc to database. Now, what alerts me - in the folder with files used for all DB inserts, all files are numeric, and created same time (same minute)... which makes me think that manually added file probably won't work, there should be some sort of compiler that rewrite/reindex those files.

I ran re-index in Magento admin just in case.

Now, needed field is in admin panel, however information after entering and saving is not going to the database. If row manually added in the database with full reference to specific record, it's not being pulled out from the database too neither to admin backend, nor to frontend.

**Question**

What is the proper process to add new attribute in Magento? How to make it talk to database?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: see here http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html

Comment: If you want custom attribute. you may have a look here. http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/

Comment: Thanks Abdul and Arjun. First link is something different from what I'm trying to do. 2nd is something I already did, but didn't achieve result. Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think you have two different issues here. If you have just added the attribute, make sure you trigger a "Flush Magento Cache" (Zend has a cache for the database structure, so that's why it doesn't save to the database, it's just not aware of the new attribute yet)

Second, if you can't get the information from the frontend, make sure your indexes are up to date (especially Product Attributes). If you are trying to get the attribute on the listing page, make sure `Used in Product Listing` is set to `Yes` under your attribute properties.